# Help parsing a page with python

Tags: python, parsing, screen-scraping

I would like to parse a webpage to can get the url of the video download. I use python and firebug but I cant get the url link.

Example:

The url where I have to get the video link is:
hxxp://www.rtve.es/mediateca/videos/20100125/saber-comer---salsa-verde-judiones-25-01-10/676590.shtml"

The video is
hxxp://www.rtve.es/resources/TE_SSAC011/flv/8/2/1264426362028.flv
Could you help me please?
Many thanks and sorry for my english!

Comment: btw, are you allowed to download that movie clip?

Comment: note that those video links are generated by javascript.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [`lxml`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/).

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that  I cant get the video link. But if I push in play button in the web page, I can download the video file with the firefox extension "Download Helper"  but I would like to do this automatically. Any help please?

Comment: Then you've misrepresented the problem. If you need to decompile the SWF file then you'll have to look elsewhere.

Comment: the videos are generated by javascript. therefore, you can't really use HTML parser for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re 
from urllib2 import urlopen
text = urlopen('http://www.rtve.es/mediateca/videos/20100125/saber-comer---salsa-verde-judiones-25-01-10/676590.shtm').read()
reg = re.compile(r'http://www\.rtv.*flv')
reg.findall(text)
```

Normallly you can use this one. But there is no your link inside.

Comment: you can also use mentioned BeatifulSoup or mechanise.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I cant get the video link. But if I push in play button in the web page, I can download the video file with the firefox extension "Download Helper" but I would like to do this automatically. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

@OP, those videos are generated by javascript. For this topic, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=spidermonkey). Or [search google](http://tinyurl.com/yk4q4mk) for references.

Comment: Many thanks, I try to find an alternative, but I don't find nothing. I have to to the video dowloads manually :-(
Many thanks!